# Airflow schedule job - how to run it before the end of interval

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to schedule a yearly job in Airflow, that runs every year on Oct 1st.
The problem is, for this year's job (today is Oct 6th 2023), the job won't run till next year (2024 Oct 1st ). I need to run past several years' jobs as well this year's.

How should I schedule the job? I can't run command to trigger the job. Thanks.

Comment: Set `start_date` to the year you want to start with minus 1 and `catchup=False` to trigger job for every interval up to the current year. If you want the job that runs (triggered by a schedule) today to be treated as a job for *this* year then you need to access [`data_interval_end`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dag-run.html#data-interval) instead of `start_date`. Because the job for a given interval will be triggered only when that interval has ended, this is by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using CronTriggerTimetable and catchup

```
import pendulum
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.timetables.trigger import CronTriggerTimetable

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example',
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 1, 1, tz='UTC'),
    schedule=CronTriggerTimetable('0 0 1 10 *', timezone='UTC'),
    catchup=True,
)
```